# entry door lock replacement

Tags: lock

My keys might have been compromised. 
My options are :
1. Buy a Kwikset rekeying set and rekey all the locks (something I've never done before but there are enough Youtube videos that I can figure it out)
2. Replace all the locks with the Kwikset Smartkey locks and deadlocks so that in the future rekeying will be a 5 minute exercise.

Any thoughts on pros/cons of each approach?

Thanks
V

Comment: If you think you'll need to re-key regularly, then smartkey. Elseways, do the re-key yourself just the once. (Parenthetically, I've heard a rumor about smartkey locks forgetting their coding and locking you out... I don't have any statistical basis on which to judge this claim, but it might be something you want to research.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is something you will only need to do one time, swap out the latchset. The chance of dropping the pins are high the first time around, but with care, it can be done. I know this from experience. The new latchset gives new longevity as well.

If this will be a recurring thing get the keying kit, I see them online and you can pick them up for as little as the cost of a new latchset, for the smaller kits. There are really cheap ones too, but I know nothing of what they have the capability of doing other than rekeying one knob.

I have no faith in the smartkey setup, but I am a purist when it comes to locks. I do not claim to know about smartkeys, but if it is a matter of putting in one key, installing a specific tool, and then put in the new key and remove the tool and it changes the lock, sounds like somebody with the original and a new key, and the same special tool can do the same.

Comment: You're correct about how the smartkey works: insert original key, insert pick-shaped tool (not special at all), insert new key, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. After reading some more reports on the vulnerability of the Kwikset Smartkey locks (see [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sR-h64WwfW8) ) I believe buying the rekeying kit and rekey the locks is a safer option.